# Android - refresh activity

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh

My android application has 2 activities:

In the first one (MainActivity), the user chooses some parameters and these parameters are sent to the second activity (Display).
The second activity calls a web service, and according to the chosen parameters, the web service returns a value. I use the returned value to draw a bar chart of the evolution of this value. That's why I created a timer in the second activity that I put in the onCreate() function:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { 
    public void run() {
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
},10000, 10000);
```

So every 10 seconds, the second activity is called again and the bar chart is updated with the new returned value.

The problem is, after the 2nd or the 3rd execution of the timer, several identical values are returned at the same time, as if the activity was called several times. And then the application starts freezing (but doesn't close).

I'm using the charts provided by this library: http://android-graphview.org/
I've also tried using the functions provided on the above website (resetData and appendData), and also the invalidate() function, but nothing works. 

Any ideas why this happens? Is my way of refreshing the activity wrong?

Comment: Why don't you refresh the chart, instead of activity?

Comment: I need to call the web service again in order to get a new value (so that I can update the chart).

Comment: Then call the web service and then update the chart. Still can't see why would you need to restart your activity. Please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to find out the correct usage of Activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you described it:

1. you create a new Timer (see 2.) with every call of the second activity
2. The purpose of each Timer is to call the second activity (see 1.) every 10 seconds

As a result the amount of times the second activity is called as a function of time increases exponentially.

A possible solution would be to move the timer to the onCreate method of your Main Activity (and still call the second activity from it).
This way there should be exactly one Timer active at any time.

EDIT:
As commented by Marius, an Activity might not be the optimal choice. If there is no user-input and the only thing the activity does is call a webservice and return the result, a method called from your Main Activity would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, calling `finish()` and starting the activity, **NOT A GOOD IDEA**.

Secondly, As far as i have understood your scenario, calling an `AsyncTask` inside a `Timer` after every 10 seconds is a better way to accomplish this. Call your web service in `doInBackground()` and then update your UI from `onPostExecute()`, this way you can avoid calling `finish()` and relaunching your activity every 10 seconds.

Finally you are creating a new `Timer` instance eveytime your Activity is called, so creating a huge number of `Timer` instances hanging your application.